# PHP mysql Query Bug

Tags: html

I am trying to load articles from 1 to 5 on the homepage of this website.

When loading the homepage, only results from ID 2 to 5 vs. 1 to 5 are getting displayed and I'm not sure why. It seems there probably is a problem with my while loop but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have added a link to a screenshot of the database to show that there is in fact an article with the ID 1 and I've also added a link to the website itself.

[Database in question](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23734472/db.jpg)
[Website in question](http://bit.ly/O6vOSu)

```
<div class="bodymainwrap">
<div class="contentwrap">

    <?php

        if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
            $page = "between " . (($_GET['id']*5)-5) . " and " . ($_GET['id']*5);
        } else {
            $page = "between 1 and 5";
        }

        require_once '/db.connect';

        $query = "SELECT * FROM Articles where id " . $page;

        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        if (!$result) {
            echo "<br />" . $query;
            die("<br/> Error: occured while trying to execute the query " . mysqli_error($link));
        }
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
    ?>
    <div class="sidebar" align="center">
        <a href="/nothing/index.php?id=2" >Page 2</a>
        <?php echo $query ?>


    </div>
    <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo '<div class="entry">';
            echo '<img src="/nothing/images/julie.jpg">';
            echo'<H2>';
            echo $row['Title'];
            echo'</h2>';
            echo '<p>';
            echo $row['Article'];
            echo '</p>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    ?>


</div>
```

Comment: you only have 4 records.  are you sure it's just not showing that, and really starting at 1?

Comment: if you look at the website, only 3 records are showing, ID 2, 3 and 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here I believe, with the lone mysqli_fetch_array call after you get $result

```
 $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
 if (!$result) {
   echo "<br />" . $query;
   die("<br/> Error: occured while trying to execute the query " . mysqli_error($link));
 }
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)  //delete this
```

Here you have already fetched the first row.  Remove that, and just keep it within the loop.  That's the underlying reason for how the while loop works.  It keeps advancing while [mysqli_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array) doesn't return null.

Comment: You mean it should look like this ? while (){ $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
    echo '<div class="entry">';
    echo '<img src="/nothing/images/julie.jpg">';
    echo'<H2>';
    echo $row['Title'];
    echo'</h2>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo $row['Article'];
    echo '</p>';
    echo '</div>';

Comment: @neilnm  I don't know what you mean.  My suggestion was to remove the lone mysqli_fetch_array call and only have use it with the loop

Comment: @neilnm I clarified my answer and added better code snippet

Comment: awesome! it worked, my mistake, I think I forgot to delete that line of code when I was doing a test before.